# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Why if I write a number in the text box and delete it until empty, I get an error like this

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
Private Sub txtPesJmlPesan_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPesJmlPesan.TextChanged
        Dim hasil As Integer

        If (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Silver") Then
            hasil = 15000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Gold") Then
            hasil = 20000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Diamond") Then
            hasil = 25000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code works well and the multiplication works well too if I don't delete it until empty.

Comment: Did you actually look to see what the input string was when the exception was thrown? It should be fairly obvious why it could not be converted to a number if you actually look at it. You talk about the `TextBox` being empty. What would its `Text` property be in that case? Is that a valid number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextChanged` will be executed for every change, even when user clear the textbox.
With empty string `Integer.Parse` will throw an exception.

You could check that textbox has valid integer before performing operations on it.

```
Private Sub txtPesJmlPesan_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPesJmlPesan.TextChanged
    Dim hasil As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text, hasil) = False Then
        lblPesTotal.Text = "0" ' Or something else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Silver") Then
        lblPesTotal.Text = (15000 * hasil).ToString()
    ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Gold") Then
        lblPesTotal.Text = (20000 * hasil).ToString()
    ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Diamond") Then
        hasil = 25000 * hasil
        lblPesTotal.Text = (25000 * hasil).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @TeaParty, please set `Option Strict` to `On` in the project, with `Option Strict` enabled compiler will warn you about possible type errors before you run application.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code slightly as below :

```
 Private Sub txtPesJmlPesan_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPesJmlPesan.TextChanged
    Dim hasil As Integer

    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)) And (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Silver") Then
        hasil = 15000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
        lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
    ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)) And (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Gold") Then
        hasil = 20000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
        lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
    ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)) And (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Diamond") Then
        hasil = 25000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
        lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to integer from an empty string is obviously not a valid format to make any calculation since the whole string is empty, what would you even do of that?

You may fix this issue by using the Try Catch exception handler as follows:

```
Private Sub txtPesJmlPesan_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPesJmlPesan.TextChanged
    Dim hasil As Integer

    Try
        If (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Silver") Then
            hasil = 15000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Gold") Then
            hasil = 20000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        ElseIf (cbxPesMenu.Text = "Diamond") Then
            hasil = 25000 * Integer.Parse(txtPesJmlPesan.Text)
            lblPesTotal.Text = hasil
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        hasil = 0
        lblPesTotal.Text = hasil ' the best code to suppress that error in a legal way
    End Try
End Sub
```